# How to get the number of clients in the room from client side (socket.io-client)

Tags: reactjs, express, socket.io

I am working with the multiplayer game using React, Express, and socket.io. I am using socket.io-client to establish the connection between React and Express server.

My question is how to get the number of clients who currently are in the room from client-side (React side).

PS. Thank you so much for every response :D